# iOS Enterprise In-House Deployment need for Device IDs?

Tags: iphone, ios

when you're Company is enrolled in the Enterprise iOS Developer Programm, and you want to deploy an App in whatever way (.ips / OTA). Do all Device IDs (10000+) have to be registered and be Part of the Provisiong Profile or is it hopefully handled another way?

Comment: Quick Question for you... If I am using Enterprise version how do I create APP's that are still secure or tied to the device UDID or similar. In other words, Lets say I develop an APP just for the Marketing Team of 60 individuals and then a sales APP for the sales team (another 60) so the normal "non enterprise" will not work. How can I ensure that just the Sales team get the APP for Sales and just marketing team get the APP for marketing? I want o be able to protect the APPS from FREE distribution to all and everyone! Thanks

Comment: @MaffoI am facing the same problem, can you please tell me the correct way that how can i publish my app in multiple employees using IOS Enterprise program? Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No you don't have to register all your devices, as specified in [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Just create a Distribution provisioning profile. Build your application signed with this profile with *"Build and Archive"* option under the Product menu.

It will open the *Organizer* window at the end and there you have the option to *"Distribute"* the app (you can choose to save the .ipa on the disk or distribute it directly).

[image: In-house app distribution in Organizer]
[image]

#### Deployment

In-house apps are not distributed through the App Store, you have several choices to deliver them to your users:

- Install it using iTunes (drop the ipa then sync)
- Through the iPhone Configuration Utility.
- Deploy it to a secure web-server for OTA install

Everything is detailed here: [Distributing Entreprise Apps](https://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/?lang=en-us#app43ad83f9).

For the third option, you may be interested by this software: [Beta Builder](http://www.hanchorllc.com/2010/08/24/introducing-ios-beta-builder/).
You give it the ipa archive and the download URL, it generates deployment files.

Comment: Does anybody know an official Apple Document that gives this Information. (I believe you, but it is a better argument ...)

Comment: No problem, It's written here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @Jilouc Have you tried this yourself? My own recent experience was that I had to add the UDIDs to the provisioning portal. The provisioning profile only worked on devices that were added to it on the portal.

Comment: @woz Absolutely, I've 9 apps deployed OTA to more than 100 employees internally, using an _Enterprise_ developer program and a _In House distribution_ provisioning profile.

Comment: @woz Do you have an _Enterprise_ developer account, or a regular one?

Comment: @Jilouc : Since you have used in House already I want to ask you how to your employees download this app , from the app store ? ...if yes  how does app store know that it is only your employees. thanks

Comment: @ila Edited the answer to add some details about deployment. Short answer: no, in-house apps are not deployed to the App Store.

Comment: @Jilouc Can I use Beta Builder to publicly distribute a beta with a non-enterprise dev account? I'm about to launch a beta at a trade show and want to distribute openly via a URL because we're not ready for the App Store. We want to be prepared for thousands of users. Do you think Beta Builder is the right solution for this?