# Will iPhone enterprise program allow me to beta test with more than 100 devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, enterprise, iphone-developer-program

Will iPhone enterprise program allow me to beta test with more than 100 devices? I wish to produce an app that requires many round of beta testing. 5 rounds of 30 for example. As far as I know there is no workaround for the regular developer program.

Does the enterprise program allow me to achieve this? And if so is it significantly more difficult in getting approved for the enterprise program?

Comment: Are you really saying that you need to beta-test your app on 30 different devices and that you will need to repeat those tests 5 times on 30 other devices? -> The "normal" developer program allows you to register up to 100 devices to test as many apps as many times as you wish.

Comment: Yes I want to test with 5 groups of 30 devices. All different devices.

Comment: In that case, get two separate developer accounts which allows you to register 200 devices (per year).

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer and Apple's Documentation there is no limit for number of devices you can ditribute your apps.
[iOS Enterprise In-House Deployment need for Device IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647309/ios-enterprise-in-house-deployment-need-for-device-ids)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

## NOTICE

Enterprise Programm let's you test and distribute your apps Inside your company, not sell it outside.

But, of course, you can buy it, test your app on hundreds of devices, than purchase Developer's Programm and sell your app in App Store.

Comment: Then why wouldn't everyone just go with the enterprise program?

Comment: You can't sell it trought the App Store)That's why)

Comment: Actually, you are mixing apples and oranges. The enterprise program does NOT allow you to distribute any Apps outside your company whilst using the Enterprise Distribution Certificate. Meaning, you are not allowed to distribute any App to any of your customers - not even if they are helping you with the beta testing.

Comment: @Till is correct. I work for a company that does iOS software development for our customers and Apple made it very clear that we are **not** allowed to use the enterprise program to distribute test builds to our clients.

Comment: @erotsppa Because it is 3 times as expensive and you need to get approval from Apple.

Comment: But what is considered part of my company? If I find 30 testers off the street for beta test, are they considered part of my company?

Comment: @erotsppa No, they are not and you would be violating the terms and conditions of the enterprise developer program if you distributed your app signed with the enterprise distribution certificate to them.

Comment: @Till so what is the correct way to test stuff like this? I mean a beta test is crucial in release software. Should I just put it in the App Store and hope it doesn't completely fail? How do companies do this? Surely they have more than 100 users testing the app before release.

Comment: Big companies have big QA departments - those users are under contract with the companies and therefor are considered being a part of them.