# Distribution of iPad app (.ipa format file) over website

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, distribution

I am new IOS development, i want to distribute my iPad app (.ipa format file) over my website. So, others can download my iPad app (.ipa format file) from my website.  So, Is it possible to download the iPad app (.ipa format file) over website by others?

Comment: You need enterprise distribution profile

Comment: Why would you do that? AppStore provides a seamless experience for your user.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to check the Box "Distribute to Enterprise" when you Archive your Application. When you do so, a plist File is generated. (Be Careful with the Informations you Provide, the URL has to be right). Place the ipa and plist to your server.

Then you can Link to the plist from an HTML File:

itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://YOURSERVER/YOURAPP.plist

Thats how you do OTA (Over-The-Air Distribution)

This is only possible with an Enterprise Profile or an AdHoc Profile for dedicated Devices, thus for Testing Purposes.

You can also use [TestFlight](https://testflight.apple.com/)

Comment: If you have some PHP skills you can generate the plist automatically from the .ipa file. Which is what we do, and makes wireless distribution a bit easier.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Is it possible that the ipa format file does not contain the particular device UDID. So, the app (ipa format file) can run on that device.

Comment: That is only possible if you have an Enterprise Distribution Certificated which is only issued to Enterprise and is intented to in-House Use only.

Comment: Hi Maffo, Could you please explain more detail about Enterprise Distribution Certificated?

Comment: Hi Maffo, With your below reference, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647309/ios-enterprise-in-house-deployment-need-for-device-ids and the Beta Builder supports only the IOS 4.0. but my device require IOS 5.0 and later so the ipa format file cannot install into my device.   How do we solve this? or is there any server configuration from our end?

Comment: Beta builder version 1.0 supports only the IOS 4.0 or early users. But, we require IOS 5.0 or later users. So, is there any Beta builder which is support the IOS 5.0 or later users?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the http://www.diawi.com/ for uploading .ipa.
But make sure that only register device user can run the file on their devices.

Answer (score 0):

Entrprise could be the solution, but Apple says that the ipa must be distributed only to company employees.