# iOS Ad-Hoc Distribution

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently finished with making an iOS app and I would like to distribute the app amongst my co-workers using ad-hoc distribution. I have only two months experience with XCode and I am confused about everything about what materials I need to send an app out to my co-workers. I don't want to make an error that I cannot reverse.

1. What are the essentials I need to bundle in order to distribute an app to other people?
2. What is a provisioning profile and is it needed to distribute an app?
3. Is there a way to send people an app using ad-hoc without registering their UDID's?
4. Lastly, is there a recent tutorial on creating a web link to distribute an app?
5. Would dropbox be easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You will need to archive your app and then export it as Ad-Hoc. No extra work need here.
2. [What is provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3362706/1254172)
3. No
4. [Distribute ipa via web](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11538391/1254172)
5. As a matter of fact, there are a lot of more handy ways. I suggest you to look at [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net) or [Fabric](http://fabric.io) which allows you to get more than just a deployment - it allows you to gather bugreports, self-updating and many more. Of course, don't forget about Apple's [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) service, which seems to be greatly integrated into xcode 7.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Sega-Zero. Step 1. was really simple & straight forward. Correct me if I'm wrong for Step 2. So basically, a provisioning profile is a profile that contains MY certification, the users UDID's that I authorize and MY app ID, correct? Step 3. Darn. Oh well, got that question clarified. Step 4/5. Thanks for the TestFlight recommendation. It seems that my clients will only have my app for 30 days though, & after that they have to re-install it. I'll look into HockeyApp & Fabric as well. Do you know of a way to create a link from scratch to include my beta app?

Comment: FYI @Sega-Zero, I do not have enterprise, I only have app-store and ad-hoc distribution.

Comment: You need enterprise certificate in order to be able to build in-house builds and distribute it over the web. So your only option is to use one of services I've pointed above. I use HockeyApp, it's very powerful and have a desktop app that helps to upload new builds to the web. Gather your colleague's UIDIDs, put them into your provision profile in apple developer member center, then build&archive your app. HockeyApp destkop application will catch archiving itself and all you need to do is to press upload button :)

Comment: After you upload your build to HockeyApp, invite your colleagues to HockeyApp. After accepting invitation, they will be able to install your app from safari on their iOS devices.

Comment: was this answer helpful, or you have any additional questions?

Comment: you've been a big help. I first got my co-workers UDID and updated my developer profile. Then I created a new provision profile and downloaded it onto my desktop. I then archived my app on XCode and saved the .ipa file on my desktop. I am using HockeyApps services and so far it's amazing with no problems at all. I uploaded the .ipa file onto HockeyApp and sent people a link to download it. I've tried with three different people and it works. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: But I do have one question if you don't mind @Sega-Zero; When I add a persons UDID to my developer profile and I update my provisioning profile, do I need to save the provisioning profile to my desktop or can XCode automatically sense/pick-up the update and all I have to do is just archive my app?

Comment: you don't need to do it manually. go to account settings in xcode and press the refresh button in view details sheet - xcode will re-download a new profile itself.

Comment: accept an answer, so others could find it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the app has to be rebuild after one year when distributed this way to the users. Testing with Testflight is limited to 30 days. I did not find a way to make an app for a small company without paying 100$ to apple.
Let me know if i´m wrong.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I have the Membership account that I paid $99 for, so that's all good. Can you clarify by what you mean that 

> the app has to be rebuild after one year when distributed this way to the users.

I'm also looking into TestFlight. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your provisioning profile will expire after one year.  So after year your users will not be able to run your application. You will need to extend your year membership and regenerate the profile. And rebuild your app with a new provisioning profile and distribute it to your users.