# Distribute App to multiple iPads without App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-server, apple-configurator

I have built an app for a client that would like to run the app on multiple iPads. Is it possible to do this without distributing through the App Store? Can I use Apple Configurator from the Mac App Store or distribute through the Xcode Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TestFlight.

Details: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: Testflight is used for Beta testing purposes and shouldn't really be used for general distribution of apps. @TomCoomer I'd recommend having a look at the Enterprise Developer program

Comment: @Popeye you're right. I just assumed that they are trying to distribute for testing. My bad.

Comment: Agreed that Test Flight is only for test deployments--they expire after 30 days. You'd need to keep managing and deploying builds to support your client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apple configurator or MDM if you have enterprise certificate to create in-house apps or your provisioning profile contains all the UDID's of target devices you want distribute to. 
You may find useful [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30835086/1254172) to the similar question.

tl;dr: it's better to use [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net) or [Fabric](http://fabric.io). Alternatively you may use Testflight.

Comment: If this is really for production use, it's a good opportunity to recommend to your client that they need a mobile device management solution. There are a bunch out now including Airwatch and Intune (from MSFT). On top of distribution, you can control all sorts of policy and remote wipe devices in case of loss.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just go to Xcode and export the app (Product -> Archive -> Export), and follow the steps to save the .ipa file.
2. Create a file named app.plist (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25916806/1305067)).
3. Create a index.html file with this content:

   `<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https://www.example.com/app.plist">click this link to install</a>`
4. Upload these three files to your server (note that the URL must be HTTPS, not HTTP) and clicking on the link should download your app.

Note that you must select a Distribution Code Signing Identity and Distribution Provisioning Profile in Step 1. Also, the UDID of the iPads need to be included in the distribution provisioning profile.